# Cannot find symbol - variable (Error)

Tags: java, class, methods

I'm having a bit of trouble with this error when trying to invoke a method from another class and check to see if the result = 0. I've tried looking at similar posts but still can't grasp why this is happening so any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Code:

SongDatabase class:

```
if (song1.getFileSize = 0) {        
    System.out.println("Name of song:");
    song1.setName(console.next());

    System.out.println("Artist:");
    song1.setArtist(console.next());

    System.out.println("File size (MB):");
    song1.setFileSize(console.nextInt());

    System.out.println("Duration (seconds):");
    song1.setDuration(console.nextInt());
}
```

Song class:

```
private int fileSize;

public void setFileSize(int inputFileSize) {
    fileSize = inputFileSize;
}

public int getFileSize() {
    return fileSize;
}
```

The error is occuring in the `if (song1.getFileSize=0)` line.

Comment: @Reimeus, you do see the song class right? its right there at the bottom.

Comment: @Lachie are these classes in the same directory?

Comment: nvm. look at the first answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing parentheses after `getFileSize`. You should write:

```
if(song1.getFileSize() == 0)
```

Instead of:

```
if(song1.getFileSize == 0)
```

Comment: @Lachie, don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the check mark so people know the problem has been solved.